# border radius and mouseover events

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a SVG circle and a smaller CSS circle (done with `border-radius: 50%`) over it. The CSS circle has a `mouseover` and `mouseout` events to trigger some desired behavior when the mouse is on top of it.

On some occasions, the inner CSS circle will contain an additional `div` and an `img` tag within it. The HTML code of the CSS circle appears then as such:

```
<div id="top_circle" class="over_center" style="line-height: 186.66667px;">
    <div id="track_image_holder">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" style="opacity: 1;">
    </div>
    <div id="time_holder">
        <span id="timer" style="font-size: 46.66667px;">02:30</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**The problem is, that in that case the mouse events will be trigerred when the mouse is over the rectangular bounds of the circle, instead of just where it appears on the page.**

Now, the odd thing is that the events are bound to the circle (`#top_circle`), not to the `img` tag, and this works okay when the `img` tag is not there. It's important to say that the `img` tag has as well the `border-radius: 50%` and has no mouse events bound to it.

Also something to note: The problem replicates on Chrome but not on FF.

Here is the relevant CSS:

```
.over_center {
    position:absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left:50%;
    height: 66%;
    width: 66%;
    margin-top: -33%;
    margin-left: -33%;
    text-align: center;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 100%;
}

#top_circle {
    color: #111;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #333;
    font-family: Century Gothic , Verdana, sans-serif;
}

#track_image_holder {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
}

#track_image_holder > img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 0;
}

#time_holder {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
  text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #000;
  color:#fff;
}

#timer:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
  background:red;

}
```

And another small note: The entire project is jQuery free and must remain that way.

There is a demo including the entire code here: http://memescloud.com/mediaplayer/

Here is some of the most relevant js:

```
function CAP_Player(data){

    //some code...

    this.mouseHoveringOnCenter = false;

    //some more code...

    //The function below is being called before user interaction is available.    
    this.beReady = function() {
        if(this.loaded === 0) {
            //some code....

            this.container.style.width = this.size + "px";
            this.container.style.height = this.size + "px";
            this.container.style.position = "relative";

            this.topCircle = this.container.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
            this.topCircle.setAttribute("id", "top_circle");
            this.topCircle.setAttribute("class", "over_center");
            this.topCircle.style.lineHeight = this.size * (2/3) + "px";

            //HERE ARE THE EVENT LISTENERS:
            this.topCircle.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
                this.mouseHoveringOnCenter = true;
                this.timer.innerHTML="◼";
            }.bind(this));
            this.topCircle.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
                this.mouseHoveringOnCenter = false;
                this.timer.innerHTML="";
            }.bind(this));

            //some more code...
        return this;
    };

        //some more code...
}
```

Comment: Can you post a fiddle?

Comment: So what exactly is the question you are asking here? You say _the problem_ ... what problem?

Comment: @ochi , better, I uploaded a demo (see my edit)

Comment: @gerdi, I edited my question and highlighted what my issue is.

Comment: @Tom .. a jsfiddle would be better ... just saying

Comment: Echoing @gerdi 's comment - typically, it is best to create an MCVE
(http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and add it to your question.
You will get faster, better help from the community that way.

Comment: I think `#top_circle` is still a rectangle, albeit with rounded corners to 'look' round, yet rectangle nonetheless...

Comment: @ochi, yes, that is obvious. nevertheless, I still expect the mouse events not to be triggerd when the mouse is not within the borders. Also, this does not explain why it doesn't occur when there isn't an `img` tag in it.

Comment: I wonder if, when there is no img, the size of the div is essentially zero wide and high. Thus, mouse events are hard to trigger.  Can you post some of your Javascript to see how they are triggered?

Comment: @ochi, I don't think the `div` size is 0 since it does have a background, and hides part of the bigger circle. Also it responds to the mouse events as expected. The entire js code is in the site, it's not minimized and it's in a file named `js/player-ui.js`. I didn't want to include all of it here since it's over 500 lines. I edited my question to include the parts you were reffering to

Comment: @Tom, try putting overflow:hidden on #top_circle.

Comment: 5 years later, `overflow: hidden` did the trick for me!

Comment: 7 years later, and per https://stackoverflow.com/a/65603817/613977 by https://stackoverflow.com/users/2852445/momchil-atanasov , using clip-path instead of border-radius worked for me, to avoid mouse events on hidden corners.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Css overflow border radius mouse events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36909764/css-overflow-border-radius-mouse-events)