# Css overflow border radius mouse events

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, overflow

I have following setup:

https://jsfiddle.net/t3jkwgzz/1/

```
<div class="playlist-inner-wrapper">
  <div class="playlist-content">
    <div class="playlist-item"></div>
    <div class="playlist-item"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Each playlist item has mouseenter/mouseleave events with some actions inside (color change only shown for demo purposes).

My problem is that mouse events trigger even if I hover outside of the circle, but still over playlist-item area (which is clipped by border-radius on parent.)

Is it possible to prevent this behavior, so that mouse event dont fire outside of visible circle?

Comment: This is a side-effect of the CSS border-radius implementation; it works on the bounds of the original element, not it's area after computing any effects. The alternative would be to use a method where the event only fires when directly mousing over the element computed after the border effect has been applied. To do this you could use canvas, an image map, or calculate the size of the circle in JS and then compare the current mouse position to the known location and area of the specific shape. This is not a simple task.

Comment: They don't change color for me, might be a browser issue. I'm using Mozilla Firefox and it works.

Comment: Yes, firefox not, but other browsers do.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the mouseover is applied when get in contact with the div element , if you inspect the code you can see that the zone of div is always a rectangle , instead of use div for round or create circle , use better other ways as canvas/svg.

Comment: I understand playlist-item is div, but I thought it will get clipped by parent radius/overflow. Can you provide an example how would this be made differently?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, this is an old question but I came across it while researching something similar.

You could try to use `overflow: hidden` or to use the `clip-path` property instead of `border-radius`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem solved by [checking if the mouse inside circle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/198764/how-to-know-if-a-point-is-inside-a-circle).

```
const isMouseInsideCircle = ({
  xMouse,
  yMouse,
  xCenter,
  yCenter,
  radius
}) => radius > Math.sqrt(Math.pow(xMouse - xCenter, 2) + Math.pow(yMouse - yCenter, 2))
```

Please check here https://jsfiddle.net/howareyouami/g7zL5v81/17/